# Build a library with out-of-dir sources

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, libraries

I've got a problem with CMake and the `add_library()` command.
The setting is the following: 
`main.cpp` needs the library `MyLib` whose source files are located in `dir0/libraries`. As I have many projects I don't want to copy the source files in each directory (unfortunately in this particular setting I can't install `MyLib`), so `GetModules.cmake` should take the source files and build `libMyLib.a` in my current `project`. 
However I am unable to build the `libMyLib.a`. It's not just in the wrong directory it just doesn't exist anywhere.

```
               build 
              /
       project - main.cpp, CMakeLists.txt
     /
    /
dir0 - GetModules.cmake
    \
     \
      libraries - mylib.cpp, mylib.hpp
```

**CMakeLists.txt:** includes `GetModules.cmake` and runs `get_modules()`

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
    project(ExampleProject)

    include(../GetModules.cmake)
    get_modules()
    include_directories(${MYLIB_DIR})

    add_executable(main main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(main ${MYLIB_LIBRARY})
```

**GetModules.cmake:** (should) build `libMyLib.a` in `dir0/project/build`

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
    project(GetModules)

    function(get_modules)
    set(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libraries PARENT_SCOPE) 
    message(STATUS "Trying to get it from ${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR} ...")

    # these two lines are to check if the necessary files exist
    if (EXISTS ${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}/mylib.cpp)
       message("found mylib.cpp!")
    endif()
    if (EXISTS ${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}/mylib.hpp)
       message("found mylib.hpp!")
    endif()

    # MyLib needs the OtherLib library
    find_package(OtherLib REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${OTHERLIB_DIRS})

    # adding the library -> in dir0/project/build ?
    add_library(MyLib ${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}/mylib.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(MyLib ${OTHERLIB_LIBRARIES}) 

    # set variable for easy linking in dir0/project/CMakeLists.txt
    set(MYLIB_LIBRARY libMyLib.a PARENT_SCOPE) 

    # check if MyLib was successfully built and all files exist
    if (EXISTS ${MYLIB_LIBRARY} AND EXISTS ${MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}/mylib.hpp)
        message(STATUS "Function GET_MODULES: Set MyLib directory to variable MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIR")
        message(STATUS "Function GET_MODULES: Set MyLib library to variable MYLIB_LIBRARY")
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "FATAL -- Couldn't build MyLib!")
    endif()

    endfunction(get_modules)
```

When executing `cmake ..` I get the message that `mylib.*pp` have been found but also the FATAL_ERROR! 
Why can't I build my library MyLib?

I'm very grateful for any help, idea or hint!

Comment: Commnd `add_library` doesn't build library immediately, at **configuration stage** (stage, when you execute `cmake`). Instead, it marks library for being built at **build stage** (when you execute `make`). That it is why CMake cannot find library file when you run your script - file isn't created yet. But `add_executable` command also deferred creation of executable to *build* stage. You need to use name of library *target* for link with it: `target_link_libraries(main MyLib)`. CMake itself will find library file (when it will be created) and perform linking.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now!